# load external html page in div doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, html

i have a web interface that includes a menu and a div with id "content" and i want to load many external html pages in the div using the menu, i have a problem in the code it shows only blanc.
   this is the script :

```
 <script> 
function check() {
 document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" 
data="form.html" ></object>';
}
</script>
```

and this is the code of the menu (just a part of the code):

```
 <li><a href="#home" onclick="check();">Acceuil</a></li>
  <li>
   <a href="gp">Gestion du personnel</a>

  </li>
```

and here where i want to load the div:

```
<div id="content"> 

<div class="background"></div>
 <div class="Bienvenue"><b>  &emsp; Bienvenue sur la page  d'accueil</b> 
</div>

 </div>
```

i don't know if it's necessary that the div must be empty, so please if you know anything help me

Comment: Were have you seen loading HTML using an Object tag?

Comment: @Keith i don't understand , where is the problem?

Comment: I'm not really sure how my question is hard to understand, something has made you use the `object` tag to try and load HTML, this is not really standard.  So I'm wondering where have you seen HTML loaded this way.  Most people load external HTML either using `Ajax` (old), or `fetch` (new).

Comment: @Keith i've seen similar exemples this way, and i also tried Jquery but it didn't work for me

Comment: @mery regardless of using the `object` tag, your code should still work. Can you check the browser console for errors and report back?

Comment: @the-realtom i changed 'object' with 'embed' , it works now

Comment: Why not use an `IFrame`?  it's more standard..

Comment: @Keith didn't know about it, i'll check it , thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

i changed
`<object type="text/html" data="form.html" ></object>';`
 
with
  `<embed type="text/html" src="form.html" ></embed>';`

 it works now

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure using an `object` tag for loading HTML is standard, doing this appears to work similar to an `IFrame`, so I would personally use that.  Or better still load content with either `ajax` or `fetch`..

Saying all this using the `object` tag does seem to work, here is a working snippet.  I've also include the `IFrame` version commented out.

```js
function check() {
 document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="https://stacksnippets.net/"></object>';
 //document.getElementById("content").
 // innerHTML='<iframe src="https://stacksnippets.net/"/>';
}
```

```html
<li><a href="#home" onclick="check();">Acceuil</a></li>
  <li>
   <a href="gp">Gestion du personnel</a>
  </li>

<div id="content"> 
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="Bienvenue"><b>  &emsp; Bienvenue sur la page  d'accueil</b> 
</div>
```